# What are emoticons?

Tags: android, ios, emoticons

What are emoticons in Android and IOS, are they just unused characters codes in UTF-8 that developers decided to map cute pictures to?

If so, are they standardized? (e.g. a smiley face on android is a smiley face on IOS?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Emojis are standardized UTF-8 character sequences that are the same across multiple devices.

Here's their documentation:
http://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html

Comment: Are they part of UTF-8 BMP (basic multi-lingual plane)? or are they extended

Comment: Nope, they're Supplimentary Multilingual Plane. See this wiki article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Supplementary_Multilingual_Plane